# Database/Server Design (Cookies and Indexes) - Ints or Text?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

This is a design question relating to a website I'm building.

I have a 'Player' table that will store names, passwords, last IP, dates of birth, links to avatars, locations, etc.

When the player logs in, the database will be searched for the username they entered, and their password will be checked out as well (yes, of course the passwords are hashed).  Then, they will be given some cookie that will keep them logged in.

Every time they visit a new page, the correct player will be looked up in the database using the information in the cookie.  If their current IP matches the last IP they logged in with (probably 10 seconds ago), the page is outputted with their name on it and whatnot.

Here's my question: should I have the primary key for the Player table be the player's name (a text field that I know will be unique), or should I create some arbitrary auto-incremented index for that?

Keep in mind that this also has an effect on the information stored in the cookie - whether to store an int or the user's name in text.  As well, I want to do some sort of hashing on that value (just for a little added security), so that the cookie doesn't just contain the int or the username.

So, in terms of both efficiency and design, which is the better choice?

*EDIT* Using VARCHAR for the database would also be ok, and probably faster, I imagine.
*EDIT2* This primary key will also be referenced by other tables.

Comment: using an int will probably save some space in the long run, especially if whatever you end up using as an ID field is used as a foreign key. ints are 4 bytes, while a varchar for names will undoubtedly be longer in most cases.

Comment: One thing I should note here is that ints will take up more space, as they will need to be saved in addition to the already required name field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc's comment indicates, int will be more efficient for both memory and performance.
I'd recommend against tying logins to IP addresses, some users will have each request to the server come from a different IP address (onion routers, AOL, who knows what other kind of weird corporate NATs), and being logged out all the time will be super annoying.
You may also want to consider using sessions instead of setting a cookie saying who they are logged in as. Even though having a sig would make it a bit more secure, using sessions would be safer still, along with giving you more flexibility to track information about users before they log in (for example, what page they should be redirected to after a successful login).

Answer (score 0):

> Here's my question: should I have the primary key for the Player table be the player's name (a text field that I know will be unique), or should I create some arbitrary auto-incremented index for that?

The latter.
Names tend to change.

> 1. whether to store an int or the user's name in text.
> 2. As well, I want to do some sort of hashing on that value

Please make your mind first, then ask
is it going to be hash or a plain value finally? If the latter - what's the difference then?

> So, in terms of both efficiency and design, which is the better choice?

Oh. This one absolutely doesn't matter.